# Want to know what a webclient metrics means

Tags: spring-boot, webclient, prometheus, metrics

I got the metrics using prometheus and webclient.

like ..

```
http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="aaa.com", ..., uri="/test"}   5
http_client_requests_seconds_max{clientName="aaa.com", ..., uri="/test"}  0  
http_client_requests_seconds_sum{clientName="aaa.com", ..., uri="/test"}  10
```

I want to know what a each metrics mean.
And Time Unit.. 'http_client_requests_seconds_sum' is milli seconds? nano seconds? seconds?

'http_client_requests_seconds_max' mean longest time?

plz help me....!

Answer (score 1):

- `http_client_requests_seconds_count` is the **total number of requests** your application made to this endpoint (don’t worry about the fact that the name contains the word seconds).
- `http_client_requests_seconds_sum` is the **sum of the duration of every request** your application made to this endpoint.
- `http_client_requests_seconds_max` is the **maximum request duration during a time window**. The value resets to 0 when a new time window starts. The default time window is 2 minutes.

**Reference:** [Spring Boot default metrics](https://tomgregory.com/spring-boot-default-metrics/)