# Micrometer prometheus registry status CLIENT_ERROR

Tags: spring, prometheus, webclient, micrometer

I'm using Spring boot 3 with Micrometer and Prometheus to registry metrics about web clients requesteds in my application.

Many times, is registering:

```
http_client_requests_seconds_count{client_name="xxxxxxxxxxxx",error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="UNKNOWN",status="CLIENT_ERROR",uri="xxxxxxxx",}
```

I don't understand why `status="CLIENT_ERROR"`.

In the same application, there is Kibana which does not log these errors.

Does anyone have any idea why this `status="CLIENT_ERROR"` is being logged?

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316345) I'd assume that while your application requests uri specified in the `uri` label some client error occurs (timeout, disconnection, etc.). To know exact reason, you'll need pinpoint this exact requests, find related logs and investigate error from there.

Answer (score 0):

Either you get a null response or the status code was 4xx, see [`DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2685a35c3a3016f6197e2a5586f804cdc7f2047d/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/observation/DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention.java#L118-L129)